# How do I fix a circular import in instapy?

Tags: python

I have a problem, I am using the `Instapy` library to create an instagram bot and I already have all the code, the problem is that when compiling it gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\edwar\Desktop\Bot Instagram\instapy-quickstart-master\quickstart_templates\instapy.py", line 2, in <module>
    from instapy import InstaPy
ImportError: cannot import name 'InstaPy' from partially initialized module 'instapy' (most likely due to a circular import)
    (C:\Users\edwar\Desktop\Bot Instagram\instapy-quickstart-master\quickstart_templates\instapy.py)
```

My code is as follows:

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

insta_username = 'user'
insta_password = 'pass'

session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=False)

with smart_run(session):

    session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,
                                    delimit_by_numbers=True,
                                    max_followers=4000,
                                    min_followers=45,
                                    min_following=77)

    session.set_dont_include(["friend1", "friend2", "friend3"])
    session.set_dont_like(["pizza", "#store"])

    session.like_by_tags(["programming", "hacking", "Tecnology"], amount=10)

    session.set_dont_like(["girls", "women", "sexi"])

    session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=60)

    session.set_do_comment(True, percentage=60)

    session.set_comments(["Very nice!", "Good", "Cool", "Very interesting", "Nice", "Interesting", "Nice job"])
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem ? running into the same issue after initialization of the quickstart.py

Answer (score 7):

Rename your code file to something other than `instapy.py`

Comment: not working for me. any other solution please?